# $U\times W \cong V\times W $ does this imply that $U\cong V$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, proof-verification, differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Let $U, V,$ and $W$ be smooth manifolds such that $U\times W$ is diffeomorphic to $V\times W $ does that imply that $U$ is diffeomorphic to $V$.?
>
> Is this result also true/False in other categories like Groups, Topological spaces?

In the case of smooth manifolds, I think this is true by using rank theorem since by rank theorem the map in local coordinates is of the form $(x^1,x^2,...,x^n)\to (x^1,x^2,...,x^n)$ and we can think of $U$ as embedded in $U \times W$ as $U\times \{y\}$ for some $y\in W$ fixed. and similarly, think of $V$ as embedded in $V \times W$ as $V\times \{y\}$.

> Using rank theorem we can prove that $U\times \{y\}$ and $V\times \{y\}$ are locally diffeomorphic and use the fact that $U\times W \cong V\times W $ to prove that they are in fact diffeomorphic?
> Is my approach right? If not where does it fail?

For groups, [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33589/stably-isomorphic-groups)
implies that the statement is true for finite groups.

I have a small question here if $H\times G \cong K\times G $ then why cant we quotient on both sides $\{e\}\times G$ to get $H\cong K$?

> Is the result true for topological spaces?
>
> Is there any classification of Categories in which the result is true?

Comment: I have little to no background in differential geometry, but if $W=\emptyset$ is a smooth manifold, then that might give a counterexample.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to quotient by $\{e\}\times G$, why shouldn't it work ?

Comment: the result is not true for all groups

Comment: Look up the Whitehead manifold. Its product with $\Bbb R$ is Euclidean space again. There are closed manifold examples as well.

Comment: @Mike Miller where will my approach go wrong

Comment: Similar questions for groups have been asked here a few times. For example, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2193/10513), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349826/10513),[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/835731/10513), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/882968/10513). See also [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389376/is-there-a-non-trivial-group-c-such-that-ac-cong-bc-implies-a-cong-b), on free products.

Comment: Also, I think this question *is* interesting, but is far too broad! I can see at least 5 questions: The first question (on smooth manifolds), "Is my approach right?", "Is it true for groups?", "Is it true for topological spaces?", and "Can we classify the categories for which it is true?"

Comment: The reason you can't quotient by $\{e\}\times G$ is the same reason why it doesn't work in general : an isomorphism $H\times G\to K\times G$ need not send $\{e\}\times G$ to $\{e\}\times G$ !

Comment: You do not have an approach. You are correct that the dimensions add up, but beyond that you have suggested no way to compare U and V.

Comment: Definitely not true for manifolds. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396608/does-x-times-s1-cong-y-times-s1-imply-that-x-times-mathbb-r-cong-y-times-ma for one example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't hold if $U,V,W$ are allowed to be disconnected. You can create silly counterexamples in the same way as with infinite groups: take $U = \{0\}$, $V = \{1,2\}$, and $W = \mathbb{Z}$. Then $U\times W \cong \mathbb{Z} \cong V \times W$ as manifolds, but of course $U\not\cong V$. There are obvious higher-dimensional counterexamples of the same nature. (This is similar to $H = \mathbb{Z}$, $K = \mathbb{Z}^2$, $G = \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ in groups, or maybe more accurately in free abelian groups.)

As you noted, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33589/stably-isomorphic-groups) cites [this paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/hirshon/cancel/cancel.pdf) which proves the result is true for finite groups, but also that it fails even for $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H,K$ finitely presented! It does also hold for finitely generated (but not necessarily finite) abelian groups by the [structure theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_abelian_groups), but it does not hold in general for (abelian) groups (see my example above).

As you can see in the paper cited above, it's a little tricky to get a counterexample for $G=\mathbb{Z}$, and I suppose it's also a bit tricky for (closed) connected manifolds, but it looks like Mike Miller knows of one in the comments!

Comment: Sure, but in groups where does the quoting argument fails?

Comment: The set $\{e\}\times G$ need not be preserved by the isomorphism, by which I mean the isomorphism need not map $\{e_H\}\times G$ to $\{e_K\}\times G$. "Quotienting on both sides by the same thing" only necessarily works when the normal subgroups are in correspondence under the isomorphism.

Comment: Sure I get your point

Answer (score 3):

(Making this CW since the interesting part was done by George Lowther)

First, George Lowther gave a fantastic answer to the smooth manifold question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396608/does-x-times-s1-cong-y-times-s1-imply-that-x-times-mathbb-r-cong-y-times-ma/410699#410699).

He proves:

> There exist connected closed manifolds $X$ and $Y$ with different homotopy types but for which $X\times S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $Y\times S^1$.

(This example also answers the question in the category of groups: the fundamental groups of $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic, but $\pi_1(X)\times \mathbb{Z}\cong \pi_1(Y)\times \mathbb{Z}$.)

So, in short, NO, you cannot conclude from $U\times W\cong V\times W$ that $U\cong W$.  The problem with your argument is a diffeomorphism from $U\times W$ to $V\times W$ does not have to map a subset of the form $U\times \{w\}$ to a subset of some $V\times \{w'\}$, so there is no way to take a diffeomorphism of the larger spaces and reduce it to a diffeomorhpism of the smaller spaces.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer is no, but sometimes is yes.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261788/does-g-times-h-cong-g-times-k-imply-h-cong-k-in-finite-groups/261791#261791)

You should see something about the **Krull-Remak-Smith theorem** in modules and groups and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269542/when-x-times-y-cong-x-times-z-implies-y-cong-z-in-the-category-of-finit) on topological spaces.